# Does PayPal's GetVerifiedStatus `belong' to the api caller's country?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm wanting to verify accounts for a service I have. It seems all the accounts from the USA work, but as soon as someone from overseas attempts to verify their account the api doesn't work.

I am receiving the error `580022: Cannot determine PayPal account status`. Is each region hidden from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such restriction on verifying the international PayPal accounts too . Make sure you have passed the correct email address and the first n Last name .

I just tried to verify a "Trinidad and Tobago" account and it worked fine for me .

Apart from that make sure that if the person has middle name as well then don't include it in the API call . Just pass the first and the last name .